# T-SQL equivalent for Oracle's SQLERRM

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql

Looking for an equivalent of Oracle's SQLERRM. Does T-SQL's ERROR_MESSAGE() accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's essentially the same thing...  It returns the error message associated with the most recently raised error exception, just like `SQLERRM`

**Sample usage:**

```
BEGIN TRY
    -- Generate a divide-by-zero error.
    SELECT 1/0;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that in the scope of a try/catch block.

> Outside the scope of a CATCH block, the error number in @@ERROR is the only information available about an error within Transact-SQL code.

[Technet Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179495%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

You can get the error number using @@error and select it out of sys.messages assuming it's a standard error.  If it's a user defined error, you may have to create the message.

```
SET @ErrorVariable = @@ERROR;


SELECT @ErrorVariable AS ErrorID, text
FROM sys.messages
WHERE message_id = @ErrorVariable;
GO
```